# jQuery using .on and .validate must submit form twice to validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, livequery

I am loading a form via ajax and usind the new .on() to load the jQuery validate plugin is not loaded before I press the submit a second time. I understand why I think. The on() function loads the validate on the form when I press submit. Is there any way to fix this? Before I was using livequery but that does not work with jQuery 1.9.1 or at least is not recommended. Here is my code:

```
 $(document)
.on("submit",function(event){
$("#myform").validate();
    event.preventDefault();
  })
```

This code worked before in jQuery 1.4.2

```
 $("#myform")
.livequery(function(){
$(this).validate():
  })
```

So what happens now is the form is not submitted but the errors only show when I press submit a second time.

**update:**
Thanks for new insight Sparky! I am used to livequery in earlier jQuery versions. But I understand that livequery is constantly listening for the element and puts CPU load on the client. Your code on jsfiddle does exactly what I want!

So I should not use .on() on the generated form? Instead run the validate() on the form in the callback.
This code works (inside document.ready of course):

```
$("#ask").click(function(){
     //send postdata from inputs, returns form with filled fields (defined with jQuery selectors)
    $.post("include_form.lasso",{zip:zip,custno:custno},function(data){
    // div"skjema" is filled with form with ID  
$("#skjema").html(data);
})
    .done(function() { $("#myform").validate();});
})
```

I have a lot of extras in the validate() that is not shown here. I haven't tested this but I guess it will work. Is it better to use .ajax() instead of my .post() code here? What I do is 
- when the link is clicked send the two field zip and custno to "include_form.lasso"
- fill the result in the "skjema" DIV. This is a form 
- attach the validate() function to the generated form
- I do not need a stopPropogation() on the form to prevent default submit? It should validate first?

**Update:**
After great help from Sparky here is what works:
Just wanted to share my code. I needed 2 functions for my dynamic form, validate() and autocomplete(). So I put the validate() code and the autocomplete in 2 functions:

```
function pumpemod(){ 
$("#pumpemod").autocomplete({
source: "code/sql2.php?mod=1",
minLength: 3,
delay: 400}); }

function send_validate() { $("#my_dropdown").validate()...}
```

So in the .on() code I call the functions. When I click a radio button it fetches a form. It looks like this:

```
$(document)
    .on('click','input.montRadio',function(event){
    var pnr = $("#postnr").val();
    var knr = $(this).attr("rel");
   $.post("code/vis_skjema.lasso",{postnr:pnr,kundenr:knr},function(data){
        $("#skjema").html("/images/loading.gif");
        $("#skjema").html(data);
        pumpemod();
        send_validate();
    });

    });
```

Hopes this can help someone else. At least I got a good understanding now of on(). I wanted to move from livequery to on().

Comment: The first snippet, is that the entire code ? If so you need to have a document ready , then a selector on your form element that has the .on() method

Comment: exactly ... just modify the first couple of lines and you should be fine

Comment: Where is the code that loads the form via ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `on()` function loads the validate on the form when I press submit. ... So what happens now is the form is not submitted but the errors only
>   show when I press submit a second time.

You are correct.  The plugin is not initialized on your form until you click `submit` the first time.  This is because, with `on()`, you are simply attaching the plugin's initialization function to a `submit` event.  No matter how you do this, `delegate`, `bind`, etc., your problem will be the same... you'll never properly initialize the plugin until after that first click.

> So what happens now is the form is not submitted

Your `preventDefault()` is blocking the normal submit.  You need to get rid of all this and simply call `.validate()` immediately after you construct the form's HTML.

> Is there any way to fix this?

You must initialize the plugin (one time) immediately after you load the form with your `ajax`.  Where is the code that does this?  Try putting your `.validate()` function inside of the `complete` callback function of the `ajax` that loads your form.  This will run `.validate()` once upon completion of the `ajax`.

Or if you use [jQuery `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)...

```
$('#content').load('form_loader', function() {
    ('#myform').validate(); // initialize plugin after form is loaded
});
```

Without seeing your `ajax` code, the crude demo below was quickly constructed to only simulate this concept.  Click the "test" button to load a form with `ajax`, which then initializes `.validate()` upon completion.

**http://jsfiddle.net/dUmfK/**

You can see the form is loaded into a `div` and ready to validate before the very first click.

Comment: I commented your reply in the original answer. If I understand I don't need an .on() function for this?

Comment: @asle, you understand correctly.  However, remember my answer is only focused on proper initialization of the plugin on the form.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is it good practice to initialize validate() when the specific form is loaded? I usually use .on() on dynamic elements but .on() requires an event and that was not what I wanted to trigger the function.

Comment: @asle, I was just trying to be clear about my answer... that it's only about handling plugin initialization after you load the form with `ajax`... not about how to handle any `ajax` for submission of the form data.  This may not have been entirely clear to the reader.  Yes, since `.validate()` is just a "one-time" plugin initialization, it **must** occur _after_ the form is created, and also _before_ you need to have validation available.  For most people, this is upon the DOM `ready` event.  For you, it's immediately after you create/load the form's HTML.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I really appreciate your time and insight :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mispelling..

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mFeww/4/

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formID").on("submit",function(event){
            $("#myform").validate();
            event.preventDefault();
      })
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="formID">

</form>
```

Comment: How is this any different?  As you can see, [your jsFiddle has the exact same problem as the OP is describing... no validation until after the submit button is clicked twice.](http://jsfiddle.net/mFeww/5/)  That's because the plugin is not initialized on the form until the submit button is clicked the first time. ( This is a very popular misconception. )  You **must** _initialize_ the plugin (only ONCE) _before_ the button is first clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a selector in the call to `on` to make a delegate instead of a regular bind:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#myform" function(event){
  $(this).validate();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

If possible, bind the delegate to an element closer to the form than the entire document.

Comment: The problem is still that you must "submit" before the validate() is run. Sparky is correct.

Comment: @asle: Aha, the `validate` method doesn't validate, it only adds validation. Yes, then you need to call it on the form as soon as it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").on("submit",function(){
   $(this).validate();
  return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. here is how I resolved it.

I had the same issue:
my goal: validate many forms with the same class:

my php:

```
form class="js-validate-itemForm" method="post" action="">
...
form class="js-validate-itemForm" method="post" action="">
```

my js:

```
$('.js-validate-itemForm').each(function () {
       $(this).validate({
           submitHandler: function (form, event) { 
               doActionOnItemform(form, event);
               return false;
           }
        });
    });
```