# jQuery validation: why submit button must be clicked twice in my Rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

There are two similar questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15671712/1054800) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20496840/1054800), but they submit the form through `ajax`, in my `Rails` app, I don't want to use `ajax` loading and write the following code:

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
$("#new_answer_on_<%= _activity_parent_id %>").validate({
    onsubmit: function(){
        CKEditorUpdate();
        return true;
    },  
    errorClass: "my-error-class",
    rules: {
        "answer[content]": {required: true, minlength: 20}
    }
});

function CKEditorUpdate(){
for(instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
   CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
<% end %>
```

The above code can alert error message when value of the `textarea` is empty, but when there is the available text:
When I click submit button first time I also get alert error message, until I click it second time it will submit the content to the server. I don't know why? What should I do for reducing the additional click? Thanks in advance!

Comment: JavaScript does not care about your framework or how your HTML was rendered.  When asking about JavaScript/jQuery, please show the rendered HTML and JavaScript as seen by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you've broken the normal plugin behavior by setting the `onsubmit` option to a function.  [The `onsubmit` option in the `.validate()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit) can only accept a boolean `false` as a parameter, not a custom function.  By setting it to `false`, you will disable the validation trigger when the `submit` button is clicked.  [As per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit), "*a boolean `true` is not a valid value"* (already default behavior), nor can you set it to a custom function.

[Review the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) to select the appropriate callback option for your CK Editor Update function.